# How to implement an iterator?

Tags: java, arrays, list, iterator

I'm having a problem with my class, which I cannot resolve. I want to implement an iterator to my `Interval1` class. Here is my code:

```
public class Interval1 {
    private double first;
    private double last;
    private double step;
    private IntervalIterator e;

    public Interval1(double first, double last, double step,  IntervalIterator e) {
        //chequear los datos
        this.first = first;
        this.last = last;
        this.step = step;
        this.e = new IntervalIterator();
    }

    public  double at(int index) {
        checkIndex(index);
        return first + index*step;
    }

    private void checkIndex(int index) {
        if(index < 0 || index >= size())
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Invalid Index: " + index);
    }

    public int size() {
        return (int) ((last - first) / step);
    }

    public IntervalIterator e() {
        for (Double i : this)
            System.out.println(i);
        return e;
    }
}
```

This is the class `IntervalIterator` that I'm using and this give an error such in `size()` and `at`:

```
public class IntervalIterator implements Iterator<Double> {
    private int index = 0;
    private Double at;

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return index < size();
    }

    public Double next() {
        if (!hasNext()) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
        return at(index++);
    }

    public void remove() {
        if (Interval1 <= 0) {
            return throw new UnsupportedOperationException("remove");
        } else {
            if (Interval1 >= 0) {
                //chekear el array e eliminarlo
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Start for formatting your code so it's readable.

Comment: In `hasNext()`, which `size()` method did you expect that code to call? What is field `at` used for? In `next()`, which `at()` method did you expect that code to call? In `remove()`, where is variable/field/parameter `Interval1` defined?

Comment: In `Interval1` constructor, what is parameter `e` use for? An iterator can only be used once, so second call to `e()` (weird name) will return already exhausted iterator. In `e()`, `this` is not an iterable object, for cannot be used in `for` loop like that.

Comment: For first/last/step values 3/9/2 I'd expect values `3`,`5`,`7`,`9` to be returned, but `size()` returns `(9-3)/2 = 3`, not `4`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use java8 streams to return an `Iterator<Double>`:

```
public class Interval
    implements Iterable<Double> {

    private final double first;
    private final double last;
    private final double step;
    private final long size;

    public Interval(double first, double last, double step) {
        this.first = first;
        this.last = last;
        this.step = step;
        this.size = (long) ((last - first) / step) + 1;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Double> iterator() {
        return DoubleStream.iterate(this.first, n -> n + this.step)
            .limit(this.size)
            .iterator();
    }

    // TODO getters
}
```

I've added the `final` modifier to the fields and made the `Interval` class implement `Iterable<Double>`, so that it can be iterated. I've also fixed the calculation for `size` (it needed to be incremented by one).

I've used the [`DoubleStream.iterate()` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/DoubleStream.html#iterate-double-java.util.function.DoubleUnaryOperator-), which receives a seed and a function that receives the current element of the stream as an input and returns the following element (for this I've added `step` to the current element). I also had to use the [`DoubleStream.limit()` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/DoubleStream.html#limit-long-), because the stream generated by `DoubleStream.iterate()` is infinite.

Usage:

```
Interval interval = new Interval(3.0, 9.0, 1.5);

for (double n : interval) {
    System.out.println(n);
}
```

The above code generates the following output:

```
3.0
4.5
6.0
7.5
9.0
```